# Bringing Up Weak Derivatives on Calc I Quiz

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Ok so I realize that I was being a bit of a smart ass but we had a quiz in my honors Calc I class the other day and one of the questions was:

"Is the following function $f:[-2,2] \to [0,1]$ differentable?
$$
f(x)=\lvert x \rvert
$$
Explain why or why not.

My answer was:

No, the function is NOT differentiable in the classical sense, however since $f \in L^{1}([-2,2])$, it admits a *weak* derivative given by the signum function $g:[-2,2] \to [-1,1]$ such that
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x<0 \\
1 & \text{if }x>0 \\
0 & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}
$$
since for every $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}$, subject to the conditions that $\varphi(-2)=\varphi(2)=0$ we have
$$
\int_{0}^{2} x\varphi'(x) \, dx-\int^{0}_{-2} x \varphi'(x) \, dx=-\int^{0}_{-2}  \varphi(x) \, dx \, + \int^{2}_{0}\varphi(x) \, dx=\int^{2}_{-2}g(x)\varphi(x) \, dx
$$
which is correct (unless I've made some error) but the teacher just wrote a "?" and took off 10 points (the amount the question was worth). I realize that my knowledge base is probably the exception for the typical freshman student in Calc I (even at my school) since both of my parents are hardcore mathematicians but shouldn't being as precise as possible be encouraged and not punished? Would it be worth it to challenge the teacher on this? I'm afraid to ask my parents because they'd probably just embarrass me but I really feel like I deserve full credit.

Comment: Yes in some sense.  No in that you only needed to answer the question being asked and any additional information is not effecient. The longer the message the higher the probability of the teacher misunderstanding and the more time it takes the teacher to grade. remember there not just grading your test.

Comment: If it were me, I'd gently approach the professor and explain your answer. Also understand that an undergrad TA type who has no clue what a weak derivative is probably graded it and this will be the case for the next few years so keep your audience in mind.

Comment: 1) you are being a smart ass.  2) Why are you in calculus 1?

Comment: The question asked whether the function was differentiable, not whether the function was weakly differentiable. The answer to the question as stated, then, is "No".

Comment: Surely the answer shouldn't have received much credit, for the simple reason that it doesn't answer the important part of the question: It doesn't explain *why* the function is not differentiable.

Comment: @travis perhaps but in context, I think my answer makes it perfectly obvious why the function isn't differentiable.

Comment: @DougM yes, I realize that but I think I have a good point and the only answer I can come up with to answer your second question is "bureaucracy"

Comment: If I were grading this I'd have given no credit either, because the point of the question is "why does it not have a derivative?"  You didn't explain that, so no credit.

Comment: @BadStudent You still haven't said why that weak derivative isn't a classical derivative. Strictly speaking, you could give a correct answer to the question by saying something along the lines of "this is a weak derivative such that there is no function with the intermediate value property which is equal to it almost everywhere, thus by Darboux's theorem it cannot be a classical derivative, and by uniqueness for weak derivatives no classical derivative can exist either".

Comment: @BadStudent (Cont.) But this is *far* outside the scope of the course, and an answer to a question in a course which is not in the scope of the course should not receive credit. This is a general principle in any class, and is applicable whenever the assignment does not involve research. At the same time, one could argue that you should have received a little bit of credit for giving the correct answer without giving an admissible justification.

Comment: Is the function $f :[-2,2]  \to [0,1]$ given by $f(x) = |x|$ differentiable? No, because there is no such function. (A shorter smart ass answer.)

Comment: Interesting answer, but no need to deploy a tank to squash a fly. Can you imagine responding to a middle school question $1^{1/2}$ by rolling out the complex plane? Tests are engineered to assess you on a subject. It's often in everyone's interest to engineer your responses appropriately. (PS. If you want to deliver an answer like this for whatever reason, write it as a footnote after the expected response... with perhaps a smiley face.)

Comment: Personally, I'd give you credit for your answer but the *vast* majority of teachers will take the position of TravisJ or Ian, and I can certainly see their perspective. On the other hand, I can certainly empathize with feeling a sense of boredom in a class like Calc I but your life will be much easier if you stick to the material. Like I said before, until you get to 3000+ level classes or Grad school, don't assume the people grading your tests know any more than the material contained in the syllabus.

Comment: Instead of going all the way up to something like weak derivatives, you could have said that it is symmetrically differentiable, which is a notion sometimes even mentioned in elementary calculus texts.